# attribute value as class name giving error

Tags: php, error-handling, version

I have created delete.php page that will accept class name and id as following:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric(trim($_GET['id'])) ) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
else{
    redirect_to($back);
}   
if(isset($_GET['cls'])  && class_exists($_GET['cls']) ) {
    $class = $_GET['cls'];
}
else {

    redirect_to($back);
}
```

Then I will create an object and call its delete method:

```
$object = $class::find_by_id($id);
$object->delete();
```

It is working fine on my localhost(wamp server).
However, when I uploaded it on my host (php 5.2) it is giving me this error on line where I called static function $class::find_by_id($id):
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM. How  can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does `$object = call_user_func(array($class,'find_by_id),$id);` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are you're dealing with two different versions of PHP. WAMP ships with 5.3 where `$class::find_by_id($id)` is allowed, on the other hand PHP 5.2 does not like it.

Try this instead:

```
$object = call_user_func(array($class,'find_by_id'),$id);
```

If that doesn't work (and I don't see why it wouldn't), you can always use eval (even though eval is bad):

```
eval("\$o=$f::find_by_id(\$id);");
```

Of course, the best solution is to upgrade to PHP >= 5.3 on your server, but you might not control that.

Comment: Thank you very very very much! It worked. I was too much worried, because I had many statements based on this function. Now I feel much better. huh...  what is the magic behind the mehod you've just suggested? I have never seen it before.

Comment: I'll leave that as exercise for reader, but [here are the doc's on call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).